# Is it possible to enable Roslyn code-analyzer only for certain folders/files (not whole project)?

Tags: roslyn-code-analysis

The minimum solution unit, Roslyn code-analyzer is installed for, is a project. And analyzer work for all cs-files in this project (analyze them).

I want to be able to set certain folders/files, which should be analyzed. And want analyzer be enabled only for them & not analyze other files.

The only way, I found, to limit the set of files, for which analyzer should work, is to mark some folders as containing generated-code files (by adding/editing special `.editorconfig` file) (as discussed [here](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/issues/2108)). But in my case code, for which analyzer should not work is not generated, so this solution would be some hack. And probably may have some side-effects.

I am looking for some correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found (except one, mentioned in question) is perhaps even more awful (but I don't have much choice) - to do early exit from analyzer method, checking file path taking it from `SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext.SemanticModel.SyntaxTree.FilePath`.

Looks like the proper solution is: If you want analyzers to work for only part of project, it's perhaps should be a signal for you that the project should be divided in minimum two.